# php Symfony 4 Ajax issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

im learning Symfony and now trying to connect Ajax with Symfony.
I put Ajax between javascript block in twig and put really simple function in controller file to check whether it is working, but found out it's not working.
Doesn't show alert inside Ajax, and not showing dump($r) in console as well.

this is my Ajax script in twig file
'''

```
   {%block javascripts %}
 <script language = "javascript">
   
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#customize").on("click", function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ 'test/ajax' }}",
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{
                id:1,
                text: 'hello'
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            alert('yes');
        }).fail(function() {
            alert('no');
        })
    });
});
 </script> 
{%endblock%}
```

'''

this is the Anker connected to Ajax.
'''

```
{{form_start(form)}}
    {{form_widget(form)}}
{{form_end(form)}}        
<a href="#" id="customize" name="customize" class="btn-basic">Customize</a>
```

'''

this is the controller file
'''

```
/**
* @Route("/test/ajax", name="ajax_edit")
*/
public function ajaxAction(Request $request){
  $r = $request->request->get('data');
  dump($r);
}
```

'''

I guess Anker is not responding even though I clicked it. but I don't know how to fix this problem..

Comment: Try changing to `url: '/test/ajax'`. Also your controller method should return a `JsonResponse` object.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I changed route to return jsonResponse and tried url: '/test/ajax' but doesn't show any change in network tab in browser console..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure you have the good URL in your TWIG template, you should used the `path()` method to generate your URL using the route name:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#customize").on("click", function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ path('ajax_edit') }}",
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                id:1,
                text: 'hello'
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            alert('yes');
        }).fail(function() {
            alert('no');
        })
    });
});
```

And as Bossman said, your route must return a JsonResponse:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/test/ajax", name="ajax_edit")
 */
public function ajaxAction(Request $request)
{
  $r = $request->request->get('data');
  
  return $this->json($r);
}
```

And of course, if you want to check the response content, you should open you browser console, in **network** tab and check the request response. Open the console on correct tab before click on button #customize.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I just fixed the my route and checked in network tab in browser, but it doesn't show any change...

Comment: Could you please share the actual code ? Could you try to access your route directly on browser? Are you sure you click on the good button or have the right ID?

Comment: Oh I figured it out..{%block javascripts %} supposed to be {%block javascript %}